# How to know download file extension in python?

Tags: python

This is my jpg image download source:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request
import os
import shutil
from mimetypes import guess_extension

img_folder = ("c:/test")
if os.path.exists(img_folder):
    shutil.rmtree(img_folder)

path = (r"C:\Users\qpslt\Desktop\py\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
site_url = ("https://gall.dcinside.com/board/view/?id=baseball_new8&no=10131338&exception_mode=recommend&page=1")
driver.get(site_url)
images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="writing_view_box"]//img')

for i, img in enumerate(images, 1):
    img_url = img.get_attribute('src')
    print(i, img_url)
    r = requests.get(img_url, headers={'Referer': site_url})
    try:   #폴더 만들기
        if not os.path.exists(img_folder):
            os.makedirs(img_folder)
    except Exception as er:
        print("{}에러가 발생했습니다.".format(er))
        break;
    break;
    with open("c:/test/{}.jpg".format(i), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

I don't always know the extension of the image.

How do you know the extension of the file you are downloading?

Comment: @MEdwin 
[link](https://dcimg6.dcinside.co.kr/viewimage.php?id=2fbcc323e7d334aa51b1d3a24e&no=24b0d769e1d32ca73fed85fa11d02831d03adb8a26938fb188b835cc361ca719bf93018b078fa58fefcf60e7cc5f78726f458f2c1f898d9ba953b95ee6d650e591f973ea3cf8a8d891af0a1fa397fda16c1e472541bcc1d280891f9f1d2bf490) this is image link, it dont have extension

Comment: @MEdwin No. This site is secure. I can't see the extension.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the image link has no extension (e.g. if the image is dynamically generated from a php script), then you could map the `content-type` header of the image response to the file extension using [`mimetypes.guess_extension()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_extension)

For example:

```
import mimetypes

...

r = requests.get(img_url, headers={'Referer': site_url})
extension = mimetypes.guess_extension(r.headers.get('content-type', '').split(';')[0]) 

...

with open("c:/test/{}{}".format(i, extension or '.jpg'), 'wb') as f:
```

The example above will try to use the mapped extension when it exists, but will fall back to using `.jpg` when there is no mapping (e.g. if the `content-type` header does not exist or specifies an unknown type).

Comment: A tiny typo: not `mimtypes` but `mimetypes`

Answer (score 1):

i bumped into the same problem and decided to get all the headers manually (with `request.headers.get()`)
and one of them actually had a filename with the extension

in my case it was `'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%20%D0%A4%D0%97.doc'`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to first split on the `/` to get only the last part which is, I think, the filename (including the extension) of the picture you've downloaded, and then split on the `.` to separate the filename from the extension.

```py
img_url = 'path/to/your/picture.jpg'
split1 = img_url.split('/') # returns ['path', 'to', 'your', 'picture.jpg']
file = split1[-1]
filename, extension = file.split('.') # file is 'picture' and extension is 'jpg'
```

Comment: It's not stored. You want to know the extension when you download the file.

Comment: It has to be stored somewhere. When do you want to know it? Try look in the headers of the page you are downloading.

Comment: Before I download the file, I want to add the extension name after knowing the extension name.

Comment: Then you should look at the headers. Look at @will-keeling's answer